# How you would set the index correctly in this schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql

1. sometimes I select some data with "where is_admin = 0;".
2. sometimes I do this "where is_admin = 0 AND company = 'whatever' (integer)

So how can I set the index correctly in case 2 ?

Here is how I would set the index in option 1:

```
CREATE INDEX PI_ADMIN_NULL ON users(id, email, firstname, lastname, role, company) WHERE is_admin = 0;
```

In option2 I think I would do this but I want to hear your option what would be the best.

```
CREATE INDEX I_USERS_C ON users(is_admin, company)
```

I hope you can give me some tips what can I do better or if the indexes are correctly.

Comment: Your first index is indexing six columns, that seems odd. What is your thinking there? Also it's called `PI_ADMIN_NULL` but there's no null.

Comment: What problem should it solve? With a query plan, using `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)`, and the query itself and the DDL for the table and other indexes involved, we can help you. Besides that, it's hard to imagine that option 1 is something you need, unlikely that this will solve any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no further information about your data nor queries nor performance target, keep it simple. Use option 2, a simple compound index, until you find you need something more.

Option 1 seems to be trying to create a covering index, but with six columns. I don't know how effective that will be. Seems like a premature optimization.

---

If you find yourself adding `where is_admin = $1` to most queries, as is the case with such flags, indexing can get complicated. You may find yourself having to make every index multi-column to include is_admin complicating and bloating your indexes.

You may consider partioning the table on `is_admin`. Then a simple index on `users(company)` will work. This technique is particularly useful for flags like `is_deleted` or better a `deleted_at` timestamp because you can quickly drop the partition of deleted users.

Alternatively, create a join table for admins. This also makes indexing users simple.

```
create table admins (
  user_id integer not null references(users)

  -- Any other admin related info
);

-- index the foreign key
create index admins_user_id_fk on admins(user_id);

-- left excluding join to find non admins of company 42.
select users.*
from users
left join admins on users.id = admins.user_id
where admins.user_id is null
  and company = 42
```

Then you only need to index users(company). Primary and foreign indexes handle the join. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/XIPXDC-h).

Comment: @lambdamaster I made two fixes. I forgot to make the foreign key index, and I forgot the 'left' in the left excluding join